# How to trim all lowercase characters that comes before an uppercase character in a string using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write an SQL Server query to trim all lowercase characters that comes before the first uppercase character in a string?
e.g. string value "eaplgCostPrice", remove "eaplg" and pass "CostPrice" to a new column

Comment: This might help (SQL Server): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468526/determining-index-of-last-uppercase-letter-in-column-value-sql

Comment: Yes SQL Server..e.g. string value "eaplgCostPrice", remove "eaplg" and pass "CostPrice" to a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) is used in combination with certain collations then it can function case dependent.

**Example snippet:**

```
--
-- using a table variable for demonstration purposes
--
declare @Table table (id int identity(1,1), col varchar(30));
insert into @Table (col) values ('eaplgCostPrice'),('SellPrice'),('amount');

--
-- trim leading lowercases when needed
--
select col, 
(case
 when patindex('[a-z]%[a-z][A-Z]%', col COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin) > 0
 then substring(col, patindex('%[A-Z]%', col COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin), len(col))
 else col
 end) as trimmedCol
from @Table
```

**Result:**

```
col             trimmedCol
------------------  ----------------
eaplgCostPrice  CostPrice
SellPrice       SellPrice
amount          amount
```